# The C# lock construction misunderstanding (with msdn code example)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was interested in one thing using C# `lock` construction 
Now sample from MSDN and then main question after:

The following sample uses threads and lock. As long as the lock statement is present, the statement block is a critical section and balance will never become a negative number.

```
class Account
{
    private Object thisLock = new Object();
    int balance;

    Random r = new Random();

    public Account(int initial)
    {
        balance = initial;
    }

    int Withdraw(int amount)
    {

        // This condition never is true unless the lock statement
        // is commented out.
        if (balance < 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Negative Balance");
        }

        // Comment out the next line to see the effect of leaving out 
        // the lock keyword.
        lock (thisLock)
        {
            if (balance >= amount)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Balance before Withdrawal :  " + balance);
                Console.WriteLine("Amount to Withdraw        : -" + amount);
                balance = balance - amount;
                Console.WriteLine("Balance after Withdrawal  :  " + balance);
                return amount;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0; // transaction rejected
            }
        }
    }

    public void DoTransactions()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Withdraw(r.Next(1, 100));
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
        Account acc = new Account(1000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(acc.DoTransactions));
            threads[i] = t;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            threads[i].Start();
        }

        //block main thread until all other threads have ran to completion.
        foreach (var t in threads)
            t.Join();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why using `lock` account balance doesn't go into minus;it's always ending compilation with `0` balance. 
   P.S  Sorry for my English.

Comment: Do keep in mind that `Random` isn't thread-safe so you can't use that outside of the `lock` either.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you change `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)` your program ends with a positive balance. A vast majority of the `for` loop, when it is counting to 100, is a no-op because the balance is already zero.

Answer (score 1):

The lock works as it's expected in this example, upon launching multiple threads they will all try to withdraw from the account which could result in a VERY bad functionning. How?
Well, imagine that the current balance is 40, thread 1 tries to withdraw 40 and thread 2 tries to withdraw 20, without a lock they would both succeed in doing so and the balance would be -20, which can't be acceptable.

Now to your actual concern, why does the balance doesn't go negative? Simple:

```
lock (thisLock)
    {
        if (balance >= amount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Balance before Withdrawal :  " + balance);
            Console.WriteLine("Amount to Withdraw        : -" + amount);
            balance = balance - amount;
            Console.WriteLine("Balance after Withdrawal  :  " + balance);
            return amount;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0; // transaction rejected
        }
    }
```

The lock will ensure that every thread will withdraw only if the amount is available in the balance, so the condition `if (balance >= amount)` coupled with `if (balance < 0)` will ensure that the balance doesn't go negative.

You can see this in details if you log the amount withdrawn by every thread:

```
Console.WriteLine(Withdraw(r.Next(1, 100)));
```

You'll see that a lot of them will output 0 after some time, because the account doesn't have balance anymore thus the `return 0` triggers.

Comment: everything is clear, I asked a stupid question .Now i carefully checked the code and realized that I didn't notice `if (balance >= amount)`

Answer (score 0):

You are spawning ten threads, which are started almost at the same time and run concurrently. The `Console.WriteLine` calls are time consuming compared to the decrement operation, so without the `lock` multiple threads can and will enter the block of statements guarded by the `if (balance >= amount)` (because there may still be sufficient balance by that time) **while** any of the other threads is already about to reach and execute the `balance = balance - amount` statement.

(without the `Console.WriteLine` calls, the problem is the same - the likelihood for races may be lower, but `lock` is still needed unless the critical section is an atomic operation).

With the `lock` in place, no two threads will ever enter the critical section at the same time, so in case the balance is already zero when the critical section is entered, it will safely branch to the `else` block where it says, "transaction rejected".

I think your misunderstanding will be resolved as soon as you realize that this is the very purpose of the lock syntax - to prevent race conditions over resources that need serialized read and/or write access (here, the resource is the balance variable). From there, the next challenge is the `volatile` keyword, [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% certain, but I'm assuming that the example that MSDN provided shows this with a producer-consumer like pattern. Without `lock`, things could go unintentionally wrong with multiple threads working on the same data, namely the `balance` variable. `lock` ensures that only one thread can read and write to `balance` at any given time.

Comment: But why it's never go into minus , it's ending compilation with `0` account every time? About read/write at any given time no question,it's clear

Comment: @Sparkll look at the conditions in the lock

Comment: Which renders your answer unnecessary? unless you edit it ^^